# Find a string stored in a image data type in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, imagedata

I have data stored in image data type in a sql database. The image contains few strings. I want to search for a string in the image data stored

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us table definition, and some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images!) A [mcve].

Comment: Im using SQL Server-2017,
This my formatted Text "0000776F72642F73657474696E67732E786D6C504B01021400140000000800000000005439547E740200006F0A00000F000000000000000000200000001C4B0000776F72642F7374796C65732E786D6C504B05060000000008000800FD010000BD4D00000000" and I want to find a string like "Electronically" from it